# Should my web app have its own domain name?

Tags: domains, web-applications

I'm going to get a domain name for my personal web page. It will contain my blog, photos and other personal stuff, plus different web apps and tools that I'm working on.

I have put quite a lot of work in one of the web apps, and I think it has great potential. It covers a niche in a way that no other page has done before and I can see great possibilities to expand it. Via links to webstores and ads I think it could even make some money, and if I play it right this could be *the* place to go when you're into the specific niche that it covers (sorry for being so vague).

My question is, would it be better for a (potentially great) web app like this to have its own domain name (`nameofmyapp.com`) instead of being a subpage of my personal page (`mypersonaldomain.com/nameofmyapp`)? Is the web app more likely to be found by others, via Google etc, with its own domain name? Could a "subpage" give more attention (visitors) to my personal page? pros and cons?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that you'd be better off, from a marketing point of view, having nameofmyapp.com, it will be easier for people to find and remember and looks more professional.

Comment: +1 If you're serious about it, register the domain. Not having the domain shows you're not even serious enough to spend the measly few bucks on a domain.

Comment: Additionally, you can still place a link on the footer/sidebar/about page back to your personal site.